# How does setting viewBox attribute, affects the user coordinates

Tags: svg

I have the following code: http://jsfiddle.net/fCWJ5/1/, and following doubts regarding the viewbox.

```css
body{margin:0;}
#test{width:200px;height:200px;border:solid red 1px;}
```

```html
<body>
    <div id="test">
        <!-- preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet" -->
        <svg  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1000 150" 
        xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" baseProfile="full">
          <g>
            <rect class="drag resize" x="150" y="50" width="50" height="50" fill="#c66" />
          </g>
        </svg>
    </div>    
</body>
```

1. From the fiddle one user coordinate = .2, this I got by dividing
   200/1000 (test div width / viewBox width attribute). According to
   this, the rectangle should be at (30px, 10px), with a width and
   height of 10px, 10px respectively. But the rectangle is at
   (30px,97px), with a width and height of 10px,10px (some how height
   and width is correct as per calculation.). Please point out why the
   y coordinate is wrong.
2. Then I gave preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet" as said in a svg
   tutorial pdf. It was working fine for this value. But for other
   value the display goes for toss. Please explain what is this. I
   already asked a question regarding this
   [could not able to put viewbox,viewport,userspace together and get the picture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8312393/could-not-able-to-put-viewbox-viewport-userspace-together-and-get-the-picture).
   I'm unable to understand the answer and the concept.
3. what will be the value of the ratio, if I didn't specified any width
   and height for the svg dom element container.
4. I'm seeing that the ratio 1.3, (height of the test div/height
   attribute of the viewBox), is not used. Should that be used for
   calculating things like height,y coordinates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the aspect ratio of your DIV does not match the aspect ratio of your viewBox.  So HTML puts your SVG in the center of the DIV with the empty space above and below.  Add the following to your SVG code to illustrate:

```
<rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" fill="none" stroke="black"/>
```

This will show you the boundaries of your SVG element, while the red border you put on your DIV will show you its boundary.  They don't match.

If you don't put a width or height on the SVG element then it will fill its container.  In your example you set the DIV to 200px X 200px, the viewBox will then be applied effectively dividing the 200px by 1000 user units for X and 30px by 150 for the Y (because of the aspect ratio of the SVG only 15% of the DIV height is used by the SVG, 15% of 200px is 30px).  Remove the width and height from the DIV and it will use the full width of the screen.

If you add my rect element you will see that your box is 1/3 (50/150 = 1/3) from the top extending 1/3 down, while also being 3/20 (150/1000 = 3/20) in from the left and extending 1/20 (50/1000 = 1/20) across.

Comment: Your answer is only partially correct i think.Please correct if i'm wrong.

"the viewBox will then be applied effectively dividing the 200px by 1000 user units for X" is correct.

But, "the viewBox will then be applied effectively dividing the 200px by 150 user units for Y" is wrong. I think it should be, 30px by 150 for Y.

From where this 30px came: 200px/(aspect ratio of svg) will give the 30px. So this 30px will be divided into 150 user units.

Comment: Good catch you are correct!  Your height is only 15% of your width so only 15% of the DIV's height will be used.  Therefore the viewBox will divide the 30px by 150 user units.  The DIV then splits the remaining 170px of its height equally above and below your SVG element.